# CakePHP doesn't output correct path to CSS

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Just started developing in CakePHP, installed it and configured it. However the application doesn't output the correct path to the stylesheet.

When viewing the source of the page the path to the stylesheet is:

```
/rm-lab/css/cake.generic.css
```

This leads to 404 error page.

The stylesheet loads if I try to access it through this path;

```
/rm-lab/app/css/cake.generic.css
```

Appreciate the help.

**UPDATE:**
After trying numerous solutions, I just did a fresh install of cakePHP in another subfolder and this loads the CSS fine. I think it was to do with the .htaccess files.

Comment: maybe I'm very wrong (never used any php frameworks) but try ../rm-lab/css/cake.generic.css

Comment: @Elaine Marley thanks for the help but I'm using the Html helper within Cake to output the link to the CSS; `echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your cake app is in a subfolder. You should set the rewrite base in your .htaccess file in app/webroot

In app/webroot/.htaccess, add the following line:

```
RewriteBase /rm-lab
```

Your .htaccess file should now appear as such:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /rm-lab
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yep it is in a subfolder. I added the line to the .htaccess file in app/webroot/ but it still doesn't output the correct path to the css.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a theme?  If so, you might need to switch the path.  See here (scroll down a bit):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1093/Themes

Comment: Nope not using a theme, just copied over the default.ctp into /public_html/rm-lab/app/views/layouts/

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, this seems like an Apache-level problem. Is your DocumentRoot in Apache set to the /app directory? This would definitely help. In general, I think you should examine the Apache stuff with Cake (look at your .htaccess files in the app). To pinpoint the problem, I would configure CakePHP to *not* use mod_rewrite in core.php.

Comment: His DocumentRoot should never be 'app' or any other folder holding the 'app' files.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new script in your public_html folder called "test_rewrite.php"
Access the file to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your shared hosting account. If it's not loaded, you may want to contact your hosting provider to enable it.

```
<?php
if (in_array("mod_rewrite", apache_get_modules())) {
    echo "mod_rewrite loaded";
} else {
    echo "mod_rewrite not loaded";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make the `HtmlHelper::css` method do something that it isn't supposed to do.  According to the documentation:

> (mixed **$path** required) -- The name of a CSS
>   style sheet or an array containing
>   names of CSS stylesheets. If $path is
>   prefixed with '/', the path will be
>   **relative to the webroot of your
>   application**. Otherwise, the path will
>   be **relative to your CSS path, usually
>   webroot/css**.

The `cake.generic.css` file should indeed be placed within the `app/webroot/css` folder using the `$this->Html->css('cake.generic')` code that you are using in your view.

Here's a link to the API documentation: [HtmlHelper Class documentation](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelpercss)

Comment: I don't think this is the case.

Comment: What do you mean you don't think this is the case? I also took note that the folder structure that you presented in your original question is not correct. You have `/rm-lab/css/cake.generic.css`?  The default folder structure for a CakePHP install doesn't look like this.  Could this be part of your problem?

Comment: I was trying to get the Html::css method to output the path to the stylesheet, is that not what the method is for? I am not trying to do anything else using the method. My question states `/rm-lab/css/cake.generic.css` is the path displayed when viewing the source of the web page ie this is not the path I have specified myself. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your apache DocumentRoot is set to /path/to/your/site/in/a/subdir/webroot

The webroot part is critical - it prevents files from outside the webroot from being accessible and the htaccess in the webroot folder skips loading the dispatch index.php file for actual files inside the webroot (img, css, etc)

If you have the DocumentRoot path set right and the subfolder from the root of the site folder to the cake install is included in the .htaccess file as mentioned above the pathing issue should fix itself.

You might want to let us know the absolute path on the server to the cake install as well as show us the VirtualHost block with the DocumentRoot details.